# Running nuxt js application in Docker

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to run nuxt application in docker container. In order to do so, I created the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.10.2

RUN mkdir -p /app

EXPOSE 3000

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

However, when I build the image and run the container (`docker run -p 3000:3000 <image-id>`) I get nothing while hitting `localhost:3000` in my browser. What could be the cause?

Comment: Visitors from the future, can take a look [at this cookbook recipe for dockerizing your vue app](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/pull/1483)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The application inside Docker container by default is accepting network traffic on`http://127.0.0.1:3000`. This interface does not accept external traffic so no wonder that it does not work. In order to make it work we need to set HOST environmental variable for nuxt app to `0.0.0.0` (all ip addresses). We can do this either in Dockerfile, like this:

```
FROM node:6.10.2

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

# rest of the file
```

or in package.json in the script's "start" command:

`"scripts": { "start": "HOST=0.0.0.0 nuxt start" ...}`

Or any other way that will make the nuxt application to listen elsewhere than on localhost inside container only.

Comment: Absolutely right, I didn't find your answer since I googled wrong - but had the same problem. It's also [in the nuxt FAQ docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration#edit-host-and-port). Setting `HOST=0.0.0.0` is key.

Comment: Using Paketo.io / Cloud Native Buildpacks would free you from the need to write your own `Dockerfile` - then you need to pass the `HOST=0.0.0.0` as `--env` variable to the `docker run` command ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67871934/4964553)).