# Running Nuxt.js in Docker Container build by Paketo.io / Cloud Native Buildpacks

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nuxt.js, buildpack

I want to Containerize my Nuxt.js application. I could write my own Dockerfile ([as mentioned in the Nuxt.js Google Cloud Run docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-cloud-run) for example), but [as Cloud Native Buildpacks are here to free us from the need to write those over and over again](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/11/buildpacks-spring-boot/) I wanted to simply use Paketo.io to build a Container from my Nuxt.js app.

I ran

```
pack build microservice-ui-nuxt-js --path . --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
```

and a Container was created successfully. Here's the full log:

```
$ pack build microservice-ui-nuxt-js --path . --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
base: Pulling from paketobuildpacks/builder
Digest: sha256:3e2ee17348bd901e7e0748e0e1ddccdf8a602b624e418927145b5f84ca26f264
Status: Image is up to date for paketobuildpacks/builder:base
base-cnb: Pulling from paketobuildpacks/run
Digest: sha256:b6b1612ab2dfa294514fff2750e8d724287f81e89d5e91209dbdd562ed7f7daf
Status: Image is up to date for paketobuildpacks/run:base-cnb
===> DETECTING
4 of 7 buildpacks participating
paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates 2.2.0
paketo-buildpacks/node-engine     0.4.0
paketo-buildpacks/npm-install     0.3.0
paketo-buildpacks/npm-start       0.2.0
===> ANALYZING
Previous image with name "microservice-ui-nuxt-js" not found
===> RESTORING
===> BUILDING

Paketo CA Certificates Buildpack 2.2.0
  https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
  Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
    Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
Paketo Node Engine Buildpack 0.4.0
  Resolving Node Engine version
    Candidate version sources (in priority order):
                -> ""
      <unknown> -> ""

    Selected Node Engine version (using ): 14.17.0

  Executing build process
    Installing Node Engine 14.17.0
      Completed in 5.795s

  Configuring build environment
    NODE_ENV     -> "production"
    NODE_HOME    -> "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_node-engine/node"
    NODE_VERBOSE -> "false"

  Configuring launch environment
    NODE_ENV     -> "production"
    NODE_HOME    -> "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_node-engine/node"
    NODE_VERBOSE -> "false"

    Writing profile.d/0_memory_available.sh
      Calculates available memory based on container limits at launch time.
      Made available in the MEMORY_AVAILABLE environment variable.

Paketo NPM Install Buildpack 0.3.0
  Resolving installation process
    Process inputs:
      node_modules      -> "Not found"
      npm-cache         -> "Not found"
      package-lock.json -> "Found"

    Selected NPM build process: 'npm ci'

  Executing build process
    Running 'npm ci --unsafe-perm --cache /layers/paketo-buildpacks_npm-install/npm-cache'
      Completed in 14.988s

  Configuring launch environment
    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL -> "error"

  Configuring environment shared by build and launch
    PATH -> "$PATH:/layers/paketo-buildpacks_npm-install/modules/node_modules/.bin"


Paketo NPM Start Buildpack 0.2.0
  Assigning launch processes
    web: nuxt start

===> EXPORTING
Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates:helper'
Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/node-engine:node'
Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/npm-install:modules'
Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/npm-install:npm-cache'
Adding 1/1 app layer(s)
Adding layer 'launcher'
Adding layer 'config'
Adding layer 'process-types'
Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
Setting default process type 'web'
Saving microservice-ui-nuxt-js...
*** Images (5eb36ba20094):
      microservice-ui-nuxt-js
Adding cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/node-engine:node'
Adding cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/npm-install:modules'
Adding cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/npm-install:npm-cache'
Successfully built image microservice-ui-nuxt-js
```

Now running

```
docker run --rm -i --tty -p 3000:3000 microservice-ui-nuxt-js
```

i hoped to see my app inside the Browser at http://localhost:3000. But no luck! My app doesn't seem to be fully running:

[image]

Although my console looks good:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about the `HOST` variable [in this post](https://medium.com/i22digital/development-setup-with-nuxt-node-and-docker-b008a241c11d) , which the whole problem is about! And then I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746783/4964553), since I now knew what to look for. [The Nuxt.js configuration docs state it also](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration#edit-host-and-port):

> By default, the Nuxt.js development server host is localhost  which is
> only accessible from within the host machine. In order to view your
> app on another device you need to modify the host.

And the crucial config is mentioned also:

> Host '0.0.0.0'  is designated to tell Nuxt.js to resolve a host
> address, which is accessible to connections outside of the host
> machine (e.g. LAN)

So all we have to do is to [define a Docker environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) `--env "HOST=0.0.0.0"` and run the Paketo build Container like this:

```
docker run --rm -i --tty --env "HOST=0.0.0.0" -p 3000:3000 microservice-ui-nuxt-js
```

Now the Browser should also show our app at http://localhost:3000:

[image]

You can try it yourself using the GitHub Container Registry published image of the example project:

```
docker run --rm -i --tty --env "HOST=0.0.0.0" -p 3000:3000 ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-ui-nuxt-js:latest
```