# Nodejs / Nuxt 3 Paketo Buildpacks: Container start 'failed to launch: determine start command: when there is no default process a command is required'

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nuxt.js, buildpack

I have a Nuxt / Vue.js based app ([example code here](https://github.com/jonashackt/microservice-ui-nuxt-js)), where I already used Cloud Native Buildpacks to build a container for the Server Side Rendering mode. I'm in the process of migrating to Nuxt 3.x / Vue.js 3.x and updated my Paketo build to a newer builder image accordingly:

```
pack build ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-ui-nuxt-js:latest \
              --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base \
              --path .
```

Sadly when I try to run the container after a successful build using the following command (for how to generally build and run a Nuxt-based container with Cloud Native Buildpacks [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67871934/4964553)):

```
docker run --rm -i --tty --env "HOST=0.0.0.0" -p 3000:3000 ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-ui-nuxt-js
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to launch: determine start command: when there is no default process a command is required
```

How can I build a container that runs out-of-the-box or - if thats not possible - override the entrypoint or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As taken from [this post](https://dev.to/rafaelmagalhaes/docker-and-nuxt-3-18nm) running Nuxt 3 in Docker takes the following `ENTRYPOINT` configuration: `ENTRYPOINT ["node", ".output/server/index.mjs"]`. Thus it should be easy to override this at the `docker run` command. But luckily I stumbled upon the depts of the Paketo node.js docs, where it is described [how to specify a custom entrypoint right at the Paketo build time](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/nodejs/#specify-a-custom-entrypoint)!

We need to leverage the `--env` parameter `BP_LAUNCHPOINT` here. My working `pack build` command then looks like this:

```
pack build ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-ui-nuxt-js:latest \
          --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base \
          --env BP_LAUNCHPOINT=".output/server/index.mjs" \
          --path .
```

With that solution the correct entrypoint is baked into the image and we don't need to bother with it at runtime. Thus the `docker run` command stays the same:

```
docker run --rm -i --tty --env "HOST=0.0.0.0" -p 3000:3000 ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-ui-nuxt-js
```